# why does "copying" a reference in a copy constructor still work?

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor

I have been told if you have a reference in a class you have to create `new` versions of that class rather than copy them around. Why? Because you are actually referring to the original thing when you assign a reference and so you're not actually doing anything. The thing is, why does it still work?

My GameObjects contain references to Meshes, and I can copy them around fine and they all render in the right places and everything.

Comment: Why do you feel that it shouldn't work?

Comment: someone on here told me it shouldn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy constructor is *initialising* a new reference, which is fine.

What you can't do is *reassign* the reference later.

Here's an example, assuming your class can be constructed by supplying a `Mesh`, to which it retains a reference:

```
Mesh mesh;
GameObject o1(mesh);      // OK: initialising reference o1.mesh
GameObject o2(o1);        // OK: initialising reference o2.mesh
o1 = o2;                  // Error: attempt to reassign reference o1.mesh
```

(That's assuming you don't define a copy-assignment operator. If you do, then it will have to leave the reference alone.)

Comment: *Can't reassign* unless OP provides an overloaded copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Als: Indeed. Even then, the overload won't be able to do anything about the reference members.

Comment: Yes, And eventually all the member references of `GameObject` will refer to the same `Mesh` instance, That is correct or Did I miss something? Second thoughts because I got downvoted for some reason.

Comment: @Als: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. I'm just explaining that objects containing references are copyable but not assignable. Certainly a copy of an object will refer to the same mesh as the original, but I don't see what that's got to do with anything.

Comment: sorry, don't really understand this. one GameObject accepts a mesh and the other a GameObject?

Comment: @SirYakalot: I was assuming that you have a constructor accepting a mesh - you'd need one if it contains a reference to a mesh, which you say it does. It also has a copy constructor (either the implicit one, or one you've declared yourself), and so is copyable. Perhaps I've misunderstood the question - I thought you were asking why a class containing a reference was copyable, and that's what I've answered.